# Optimizing solution of Sum of Pairs: Codewars

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, memoization

I want a help in optimising a solution of a problem, I already sort out the problem, but my code is not good enough for handling large array -
[codeWars : Sum of Pairs - problem](https://www.codewars.com/kata/sum-of-pairs/)

Here is my code -

```
var sum_pairs=function(e, sum){

var result=null;
var arrLen=e.length;
for(let i=0;i<arrLen-1;i++){
  let nextIndex=e.slice(i+1,arrLen).indexOf(sum-e[i]);
  if(nextIndex>=0){ 
    result=[e[i],e[nextIndex+1+i]];
    arrLen=nextIndex+1+i; 
  }
}
return result;
}
```

Well, I know this is not a good solution. Anyway, this passes all the test cases but failed when it encounter large array - 
[Result On codewars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F2lq.png)

I want to know how to optimise this code, and also Learn any technique to writing a good code.

Comment: Here is link  - https://www.codewars.com/kata/sum-of-pairs/train/javascript

Comment: (`Here is link` - replace the image reference in your question with that (_train/<language>_ part or not).) The problem is ill defined: What is the definition of _order of appearance_, when is a pair _earlier_? If it was _lowest index first_, you just have to know if there is a value at a different index that sums to the given sum. If it is _lowest sum of indices, with lowest index to break ties_, you need to get smarter… (Note that you are welcome to answer your own question.)

Comment: `I want to know how to optimise this code` - don't - the algorithm is not up to handling sizeable arrays. `I want to [… learn] any technique [for writing] good code` You started with _The most simple thing that might work_: good. You consider each index as a possible first index - looks inevitable. Disregarding, for the moment, the complexity of ECMAScript `slice`: How much effort is each _membership query_ using `indexOf(sum-e[i])`? Total effort? What is the required result, and what does your `sum_pairs` do once a matching pair has been found? (Imagine an array of 10,000,000 zeros, sum zero)

Comment: @greybeard  you mean to say `let nextIndex=e.slice(i+1,arrLen).indexOf(sum-e[i]);` this line taking more time,

Comment: I fully expect `array.indexOf(value)` to take time linear in the number of elements/_length_ of `array` (in an unsuccessful search). `more time` compared to _what_? That is definitely where a lot of time is going, in addition to not stopping the moment you know the result.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One solution is to use `Set` data structure to memorize the numbers all ready iterated over. Then we can check for each element if there has been a number which sums to `s`. The set has an average constant time complexity for insert and search making the algorithm linear in time (and space).

```
var sum_pairs=function(ints, s){
  if (ints.length < 2) return undefined; //not enough numbers for pair.
  let intSet = new Set()
  intSet.add(ints[0]);
  for (let i=1; i < ints.length; ++i){
    let needed = s-ints[i];
    if (intSet.has(needed)){//check if we have already seen the number needed to complete the pair.
      return [needed,ints[i]];
    }
    intSet.add(ints[i]);//if not insert the number in set and continue.
  }
  return undefined;//No answer found
}
```

Comment: What does this return for the third example: `sum_pairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5],         10)`?

Comment: It does pass all the tests on codeWars so I assume  `[3,7]`.

Comment: Awesome, using `set` is a great idea, Thanks :).

Comment: Great answer. BTW while using `Set` make more sense in this case (because it avoids repetition), I tried to use a good old `Object` and it work as well.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sumPairs (ints, s) {
 if (ints.length<2) return undefined
  let inSet = new Set()
  for (let i= 0;i<ints.length;i++){
    let need = s-ints[i]
    if( inSet.has(need)){
      return [need,ints[i]]
    }
    inSet.add(ints[i])
  }
  return undefined
}
```

Comment: That is the exact same code as the accepted answer, with just a slight modification to make it less optimal (and more readable, sure, but the question was about performance war).